# visual mxml creator - fireworks, photoshop, others

Tags: apache-flex, photoshop, fireworks

I have a mature Flex app that visually sucks.

If i could, i would use photoshop craft a killer design and then use fireworks, line up my slices and export as mxmxl with the assets... and manually retrofit my project.

Issue is fireworks wont crop out the slices when going to mxml, it takes the stage as one big image.

What tool/process is 'like' using fireworks to create the flex ui?

I must be missing something.  Thansk in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [Flash Catalyst](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashcatalyst/).  It takes your Adobe assets and lets you skin them as Flex components.

My designer is using Illustrator to build a beautiful UI, and then she morphs it into a Flex project using Catalyst.  I'd be lying if I said it was that easy... I need to do some real massaging of the Catalyst export... but the export IS a Flex project and the workflow works well enough to make my app look like her design.